# Java move GUI panel While loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a panel. I want to move the panel, inside a `while` loop, to the left and then to the right, after pressing a button and until a certain condition is met. But for this question let's say continuously. After it finishes an iteration, it doesn't move left or right. I used `repaint()` and `Thread.sleep(1000)` but nothing shows up. Please help me

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        jPanel1.setLocation(jPanel1.getLocation().x + 5, jPanel1.getLocation().y);
        i++;
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        repaint();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        jPanel1.setLocation(jPanel1.getLocation().x - 5, jPanel1.getLocation().y);
        i++;
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Thread.sleep() in the gui thread will freeze the gui.

Comment: Maybe use a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: i tried to use a timer but i don't know how to make it work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688100/using-sleep-in-swing.

Comment: *i tried to use a timer but i don't know how to make it work* - and did you search the forum for examples? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907282/131872 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816604/131872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We meet [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942098/java-dynamically-add-a-button-to-a-panel)!

I managed to implement the moving `JPanel` using a *Swing* [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Since you want to move the `JPanel`, you need to place it in a parent [container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) that is large enough to allow the `JPanel` to be placed in different locations within it. You also need to use a null [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) because most layout managers will ignore calls to method `setLocation()`.

More explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MovePane implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  START = "Start";
    private static final String  STOP = "Stop";

    private int  diff;
    private JButton  startButton;
    private JButton  stopButton;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  jPanel1;
    private Timer  timer;

    public MovePane() {
        diff = 10;
    }

    @Override // jva.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case START:
                launchTimer();
                break;
            case STOP:
                stopTimer();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip, boolean enabled) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.setEnabled(enabled);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        startButton = createButton(START, KeyEvent.VK_M, "Sets panel in motion.", true);
        buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
        stopButton = createButton(STOP, KeyEvent.VK_P, "Stops panel motion.", false);
        buttonsPanel.add(stopButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(null);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1.setBounds(10, 200, 50, 50);
        jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2, true));
        mainPanel.add(jPanel1);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void launchTimer() {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer(0, e -> movePanel());
            timer.setDelay(500);
        }
        timer.start();
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        timer.stop();
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void movePanel() {
        Point location = jPanel1.getLocation();
        if (location.x > 180) {
            diff = -10;
        }
        else if (location.x < 10) {
            diff = 10;
        }
        location.x += diff;
        jPanel1.setLocation(location);
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Move");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MovePane());
    }
}
```

*Swing* is event driven. Events are added to a queue and then read off the queue and performed. Setting the location of a `JPanel` is an event. Calling events in a loop just floods the queue with events and some may be lost. That's why there is the *Swing* `Timer` class. In the above code, every half second I change the location of `jPanel1`.

Comment: *Calling revalidate() tells the parent container of jPanel1 to redraw its contained components.* - actually it invokes the layout manager, which will typically cause a repaint() to be invoked automatically, so it is not needed. You typically only revalidate a parent panel when components are added/removed to invoke the layout manager. Also Swing components are smart enough to repaint() themselves when a property of the component is changed. So in this cause the repaint() is not needed either, since invoking the setLocation() method on the panel will cause it to invoke repaint() on itself.

Comment: Edited as per @camickr [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063791/java-move-gui-panel-while-loop/64066428#comment113291694_64066428)